# Ram tests do not match with Advertised Ram speed

Tags: memory, ddr

I have 32 GB of Ram on a Windows 11 Machine.4 *8 GB

Per My motherboard Manual :
Supported Ram:4 x DIMM, Max. 128GB, DDR4 4400(O.C.)/4000(O.C.)/3866(O.C.)/3600
(O.C.)/3466(O.C.)/3200/3000/2800/2666/2400/2133 MHz, Un-buffered
Memory*

[image]

When I look at Ram part itself I see:]

Crucial DD4 3200MHZ (2 of these)
Balistix DDR4 3000MHZ (2 of these)

But When I do the tests (for example CPU-Z) I got much lower speeds:
[image]

Is this correct? I mean look at picture it says DDR-4-3200(1600MHZ)
From where 1600MHZ came from? is it because I have 2 of these 1600*2-3200???

Task manager result is even worse: showing just 2133MHZ

Comment: Note that the JEDEC/XMP SPD profile speeds are per-channel ratings in the CPU-Z screen, so multiply it by two to get the ram speed that is advertised for that profile. Note that CPU-Z actually has it right, each chip is half its label speed, since they are designed to be installed in pairs on two parallel channels. now as for the 2133, what is your CPU model? 2133 is the lowest of the speeds you have discussed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If bought  a speedy RAM, chance are that RAM isn’t actually running at its advertised speed. RAM will always run at slower speeds unless you manually tune enable  XMP.

This option isn’t available on every motherboard’s BIOS. If you built your own gaming computer and bought RAM advertised with fast speeds, you should definitely have XMP as an option.

Comment: Well, not always - before DDR3 memory would max out by default. But with DDR3 and newer the JEDEC standard caps at relatively low frequency. Most modules "officially" support "unofficial" frequencies higher than the standard allows, but they have to be enabled manually.

Answer (score 0):

The naming of RAM sticks is a bit of a mess.

DDR means Double Data Rate. So at a clock frequency of 1600Mhz, there are 3200 data transfers (one on the rising voltage edge and one on the falling edge). This has nothing to do with having two RAM sticks nor anything to do with dual channel features on the motherboard.

Of course DDR4-3200 looks better than DDR4-1600MHz. So most of the time the larger number is used.

But because you are running sticks with mixed speeds 3200 and 3000, you are never going to get any of them running at 3200.

Further each stick has a number of "profiles" build into a SPD chip on the memory stick. These are the JDEC and XMP columns in your CPU-Z screen shot above. You can usually select your preferred profile from BIOS. At the moment it looks like you are running the JDEC #7 or #8 profile to give the 2133Mhz value in Windows (after the x2 DDR multiplier is applied).

There is also the PC-XXXX naming (like PC3-12800) for transfer speeds, to add more confusion. But we'll ignore that here.